# how to use vlookup for multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i am looking for a multiple vlookup funciton.
for examle . problem statement:
I have 3 columns:a,b,c. 
how can i get result c based on a and b match together?
Is there any function to solve this?

Comment: Hey please look at the [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: There are multiple ways doing what you want. Have a look around this website as this question has been asked numerous times. Do some research yourself first and post a question when you get stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the `IF` function?

`=IF (logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])`.

What the logical test is is really up to your creativity.

Detailed explanation [here](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-if-function).